# How to configure flatpak on CentOS?

Tags: centos, software-installation, yum, programming, flatpak

I don't believe `flatpak` is configured:

```
$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description:    CentOS Linux release 8.2.2004 (Core)
Release:    8.2.2004
Codename:   Core

$ flatpak --version
Flatpak 1.6.2

$ flatpak search uml
No matches found

$ flatpak remotes

$
```

I need a repo?

```
wget https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
```

How do I add that to flatpak?

Answer (score 2):

that was rather easy:

```
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://dl.flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
```

at least as a [starting](https://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/using-flatpak.html) point:

```
$ flatpak remotes
Name    Options
flathub system
```